# How to call DLL function using "&" parameter?

Tags: perl, winapi

I am using Win32::API for perl and I am trying to call a function declared as following in my header file:

```
void __stdcall GetStepMotorHomeStatus(bool &xhome,bool &yhome,bool &zhome,bool &rhome);
```

If I import it as is:

```
Win32::API->Import('CSCInterface.dll', 'void __stdcall GetStepMotorHomeStatus(BOOL &xhome,BOOL &yhome,BOOL &zhome,BOOL &rhome);');
```

I get an error: **"Win32::API::parse_prototype: bad prototype"**.

How can I import and pass the params?

Thanks

Comment: For starters, `bool` and `BOOL` aren't the same type. Then, personally I'd use functions with a C interface for crossing DLL boundaries.

Comment: @Medinoc If I use `bool`, I get "WARNING unknown output parameter".

Comment: Ah, sorry. Then you should use `int`, since the WinAPI `BOOL` is a typedef to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference is really just a pointer the compiler doesn't allow you to change. Pass a pointer to a memory large enough to hold a `bool`.

---

Win32::API's pointer magic has gotten in my way before. I just avoid it entirely unless I'm passing in a `LPCSTR`.

The steps needed are:

- Allocate enough memory.
- Initialize it if needed.
- Obtain the pointer to that memory block.
- Tell Win32::API the library expects a `LONG` to pass the pointer as-is.

```
# Value to pass in.
my $xhome = 0;

# Allocate (and initialize) memory.
my $packed_xhome = pack('C', $xhome);

# Pointer to the string buffer of $packed_home as a number.
my $packed_xhome_ptr = unpack('L', pack('P', $packed_xhome));
```

You can use the following to verify that the pointer is correct:

```
use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );
Dump($packed_xhome);                  # PV = 0x1239de0 "\0"\0
printf("0x%x\n", $packed_xhome_ptr);  # 0x1239de0
```

Once the function is called, you can use the following to get the modified value.

```
my $xhome = unpack('C', $packed_xhome);
```

Comment: Ok, so I should import as `... BOOL *xhome,BOOL *yhome...` and call by `func(\$myvar)`?

Answer (score 0):

My working code is actually a bit different from @ikegami's answer. I changed the '&' to '*' in the import and unpacked the variable right away:

```
Win32::API->Import('CSCInterface.dll', 'void __stdcall GetStepMotorHomeStatus(BOOL *xhome,BOOL *yhome,BOOL *zhome,BOOL *rhome);');


my $xhome = 0;
...
GetStepMotorHomeStatus($xhome,$yhome,$zhome,$rhome);

$xhome = unpack('C', $xhome);
...
```